# cancel a transaction in MySQL InnoDB instead of commit or rollback

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, innodb, cancellation

I am using a transaction in a MySQL InnoDB database to perform 2 inserts. However, if the first insert fails, I would like to simply "cancel" the transaction. Is there a good approach to "cancel" the transaction rather than using `commit` or `rollback`?

For example, in php, I am doing the following:

```
$connection->beginTransaction();
$affectedRows = $tableOne->insertIgnore('example data');
if ($affectedRows == 0) {
    $connection->rollback();
} else {
    $tableTwo->insert('more example data');
    $connection->commit();
}
```

As you can see, I am using `rollback` to cancel the transaction, but this is a misnomer because there actually is nothing to rollback.

Comment: "Rolling back" a transaction is actually canceling it.

Comment: yep. rollback is analogous to cancel.

Comment: Okay, thank you. In this case I'll just use "rollback" in our code.

Comment: Don't see a problem. Would probably incorporate a try/catch block.

Comment: I would use try/catch, but no exceptions are thrown in this case. We are using an insert ignore because many inserts are expected to be duplicates.

Comment: By "cancel" do you mean "undo" the first `INSERT`?  If so, `ROLLBACK`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really no concept of canceling a transaction. Instead, you need to do a `rollback`. Alternatively, you can also do nothing. If the connection object has an uncommitted transaction when it goes out of scope, or it is otherwise closed, the transaction will automatically be rolled back.

In other words, it's alright if there is nothing to rollback, because underneath the hood, the DB driver will handle this case gracefully.

Comment: Well, this code resides within a method, and $connection is injected into the class. I wonder if the transaction will gracefully cancel when the method returns. Regardless, for the purpose of maintaining clean code, we'll just use a rollback.

Comment: It depends upon the scope of the connection. Look at what is injecting the connection and figure out what the scope is. My guess is that it's a per request scope, which means the connection will be closed once the request completes.